# Why does not MouseLeftButtonUp fire in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mouseevent

Why does not the MouseLeftButtonUp on my Canvas fire in my WPF app?
Here is the XAML:

```
<Grid Height="300" Width="400">
    <Canvas Name="canvas" MouseMove="canvas_MouseMove" MouseLeftButtonUp="canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp" Background="LightGray"/>
</Grid>
```

And the code:

```
    private bool hasClicked = false;

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.hasClicked)
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.None;
            this.canvas.Children.Clear();
            this.insertRectangle(false);
        }
    }

    private void insertRectangle(bool filled)
    {
        Rectangle rect = createRect(filled);
        Point pos = Mouse.GetPosition(this.canvas);
        Canvas.SetLeft(rect, pos.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(rect, pos.Y);
        this.canvas.Children.Add(rect);
    }

    private Rectangle createRect(bool fill)
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.Height = 50;
        rect.Width = 120;
        if (fill)
        {
            rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        }
        else
        {
            rect.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        }
        return rect;
    }

    private void canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.hasClicked = true;
        this.insertRectangle(true);
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
    }
```

Edit: I have tried adding a background colour to the canvas, but still the event is not fired. It seems like the MouseMove somehow overrides the MouseLeftButtonUp.

Edit2: If I remove the MouseMove event, mouseLeftButtonUp will fire.

Edit3: Bigger code example.
       In the insertRectangle method, if I use

```
 Canvas.SetTop(rect, 50);
 instead of 
 Canvas.SetTop(rect, pos.Y);
```

the events fires just fine.

Comment: Your code is not problem for me. The both events were fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By not clearing the canvas, but instead moving the preview rectangle in the mouseMove method solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't set a `Background` on the canvas, it doesn't seem to pay attention to your mouse events.

Try:

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas Name="canvas"
            MouseMove="canvas_MouseMove"
            MouseLeftButtonUp="canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp"
            Background="White" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: It does not fix it. It seems like the mouseMove somehow interferes with the event.

Comment: @eflles: Does your grid have any size?

Comment: @eflles: How are you determining the event isn't firing?  If you have breakpoints in both methods, the mouse move breakpoint will have triggered before you could even mouse down, and you're going to have to move the mouse off the canvas to respond to the breakpoint firing, so you'll never get a mouse up.  If you have the code in your original question, then you're going to get both events.  Try writing out to a log file to verify this, or removing the breakpoint for mouse move.

Comment: On MouseMove I draw a rectangle that follows the mouse cursor. I put a break point on the MouseLeftButtonUp.